# Draw under mouse pointer at the desktop

Tags: c#, mouseevent, draw

I want to draw under the mouse cursor at the desktop (not only over my form). I tried a topmost maximized transparent form, but I cant get the mouse move event becouse the form is transparent.

To make it transparent:
Background color = TransparencyKey color

---

I am able to get the mouse position (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C?msg=4189292#xx4189292xx) and draw to screen using the Paint event :D

Answer (score 1):

Set the form opacity to 1% instead of 0%.

Comment: opacity is 100%. The background coor is the same of the transparentKey color, this way the mouse works at the desktop.

Comment: You can draw on a form that is overtop of the desktop, but drawing to a window that you don't own (eg The Desktop, which is owned by the system) is a terrible idea.  Drop the TransparentKey and set the opacity to 1% (this captures the mouse input).. then create a new form that uses the LayeredWindow API (this is what you draw to)

Comment: But I want to draw at the form that is overtop, the problem is that I cant get the mouse position anymore. If I use the opacity instead of the transparencyKey I can get the mouse position, but I cant click at the desktop.

Comment: The mouse position Ive solved with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C?msg=4189292#xx4189292xx. But I need to draw over the form now